# Linked List implementation in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, linked-list

I'm a data scientist attempting to build stronger CS fundamentals, particularly in Data Structures & Algorithms.

Below is my attempt at implementing a Singly Linked List. Looking for advice regarding:

1. Code style
2. Can space/time complexity of methods be improved?
3. Debugging in case I missed any edge cases
4. Checking for premature optimizations

## Demonstrates implementation of a linked list and helper Node class

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


class Linkedlist:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.head = Node()
        self.tail = self.head
        self.size = 0
        # Nodes indexes defined from 0, 1, ..., N - 1 (where N = self.size) but are counted as First Node, Second Node, ..., Nth-Node respectively
        self._args = args
        if len(self._args) > 0:
            for val in self._args:
                self.append(val)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def _get_prev_node(self, index):
        """gets Node previous to given index
        i.e. if index is 1, will return Node 0 (1st Node)
        i.e. if size of linked list is 6 & index is -3, will return Node 3 (4th Node)
        """
        if index < 0:
            index += self.size
        cur_node = self.head
        prev_node_number = 1
        while prev_node_number < index:
            cur_node = cur_node.next
            prev_node_number += 1
        return cur_node

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index >= self.size or index < -self.size:
            raise IndexError
        elif index == 0 or index == -self.size:
            return self.head.value
        else:
            prev_node = self._get_prev_node(index)
            cur_node = prev_node.next
            return cur_node.value

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        if index >= self.size or index < -self.size:
            raise IndexError
        elif index == 0 or index == -self.size:
            self.head = self.head.next
        else:
            prev_node = self._get_prev_node(index)
            prev_node.next = prev_node.next.next
            if index == -1 or index == self.size - 1:
                self.tail = prev_node
        self.size -= 1

    def __repr__(self):
        values = []
        cur_node = self.head
        for _ in range(self.size):
            values.append(str(cur_node.value))
            cur_node = cur_node.next
        return ' -> '.join(values)

    def append(self, value):
        if self.head.value is None:
            self.head.value = value
        else:
            new_node = Node(value)
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        self.size += 1

    def prepend(self, value):
        if self.head.value is None:
            self.head.value = value
        else:
            new_node = Node(value)
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node
        self.size += 1

    def insert(self, value, index):
        # Inserts node with value before given index
        if abs(index) > self.size:
            raise IndexError
        elif index == 0 or index == -self.size:
            self.prepend(value)
        elif index == self.size:
            self.append(value)
        else:
            prev_node = self._get_prev_node(index)
            new_node = Node(value)
            new_node.next = prev_node.next
            prev_node.next = new_node
            self.size += 1


def main():
    def disp_attributes(lnk_list_obj):
        print(f'Linked List: {lnk_list_obj}')
        print(f'\tSize: {len(lnk_list_obj)}')
        print(f'\tHead node value: {lnk_list_obj.head.value}')
        print(f'\tTail node value: {lnk_list_obj.tail.value}')

    print('<< Instantiate empty Linked List >>')
    lnk = Linkedlist()
    disp_attributes(lnk)

    print('<< Append -3, 1, 0 to Linked List >>')
    values = -3, 1, 0
    for val in values:
        lnk.append(val)
        disp_attributes(lnk)

    print('<< Prepend -12 to Linked List >>')
    lnk.prepend(-12)
    disp_attributes(lnk)

    print(f'Linked List value at first Node: {lnk[0]}')

    print('<< Instantiate Linked List with values 1, -2, -6, 0, 2 >>')
    lnk2 = Linkedlist(1, -2, -6, 0, 2)
    disp_attributes(lnk2)

    print('<< Prepend 6 to Linked List >>')
    lnk2.prepend(6)
    disp_attributes(lnk2)

    print(f'Linked List value at second Node: {lnk2[1]}')

    print('<< Delete First Node >>')
    del lnk2[0]
    disp_attributes(lnk2)

    print('<< Delete Last Node >>')
    del lnk2[-1]
    disp_attributes(lnk2)

    print('<< Append 7 to LinkedList >>')
    lnk2.append(7)
    disp_attributes(lnk2)

    print('<< Delete 3rd Node >>')
    del lnk2[2]
    disp_attributes(lnk2)

    print('<< Insert -10 before 2nd Node >>')
    lnk2.insert(-10, 1)
    disp_attributes(lnk2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You are not allowed to significantly change your question post after someone posts an answer.  Doing so can invalidate answers.  See [what should I do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for ways you can continue a review after incorporating suggested changes.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @AJNeufeld I have made edits according to your above comments and have created a new question here [Singly Link List edits](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/207192/implementation-of-singly-linked-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `"""docstrings""""` for each public class and method, describing what it does and how to use it.

---

## `class Node`

This class has members `value` and `next`, which are not for use outside of the linked list implementation.  You should rename these member to `_value` and `_next`, to indicate they are "private".

Actually, `Node` itself is an implementation detail of the `LinkedList`, so you could name it `class _Node`, and/or encapsulate it within the `LinkedList` class itself.

```
class LinkedList:
    """
    A data structure providing O(1)-time insertion/deletion of items
    to/from the head and tail of the list.
    """

    class _Node:
        def __init__(self, value=None):
            self._value = value
            self._next = None

    # ... remainder of LinkedList class ...
```

Consider using `__slots__` to make you `Node` class faster and consume less memory:

```
    class _Node:
        __slots__ = ('_value', '_next')

        def __init__(self, value=None):
            self._value = value
            self._next = None
```

---

## `class LinkedList`

Why are you storing `self._args = args` in the constructor?  It is never used later on, so is just wasted storage.  The `if` statement is unnecessary, if `args` is an empty list, iterating over it will iterate zero times.  Simply use:

```
        for val in args:
            self.append(val)
```

---

Your indexing is complex enough for a special comment describing how they work,
so they are complex enough to benefit from a common normalization function.  Then you wouldn't need to always test for two values (`if index == value or index == value - self.size:`); just the one normalized value can be used (`if index == value:`).

---

### Iteration

Something that is always done for collections is iterating over all elements.  You should define an `__iter__(self)` method which returns an iterator for the collection.

Since iteration over a collection can be non-deterministic if the collection changes during iteration, you should track the number of times the collection is modified (insert/remove), memorize that value in the iterator when it is first created, and fast-fail the iterator if the value changes.

---

### `__repr__(self):`

> Called by the repr() built-in function to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned.

Your repr method could use `values.append(repr(cur_node.value))` and `return 'LinkedList(' + ', '.join(values) + ')'` to return a more compliant representation.

Or you could rename the method to `__str__(self)`, and leave the body unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I agree with all your points, made the edits you suggested, and learned about `__slots__`, but struggled a bit with the iteration protocol. Is my implementation `O(n^2)`? If so, is there a simple way to make iteration in linear time that I'm missing? Also, I feel I didn't account for the collection changing during iteration?